# C++ classes. Code wont works

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write my own game, and faced to interesting problem

What's wrong with class cruiser? why does it wont work?
Help me please
I really read a lot about this

P.s: it's doesn't compile due to 59, 60, 69, 70 etc.
with error: expected primary-expression before "." token

P.s: i googled it about 2 days

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_draw.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>

using namespace std;
class cruiser;

class level
{

    public:
    level(SDL_Surface *battleground)
    {
        screen = battleground;
        SDL_Surface *background = SDL_LoadBMP("textures/phone.bmp");
        SDL_BlitSurface(background,NULL,screen,NULL);
        SDL_Flip(screen);
        cruiser cruiser(SDL_Surface *screen);
        //SDL_Delay(4000);
    }
    private:
        SDL_Surface *screen;

    friend cruiser;
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Surface *screen;
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)) //проверка на ошибку вывода SDL_init
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Ошибка SDL: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    atexit(SDL_Quit);                  //выход после успешного включения SDL_init
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(1024,768,32,SDL_ANYFORMAT); //пока юзается ток разрешения формата 4:3, мб исправлю чё, но вроде норм
    if(!screen)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to set 1024x768 video: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
   // SDL_Quit();
    level level(screen);
    return 0;
}
class cruiser
{
    public:
    cruiser(SDL_Surface *screen)
    {
        SDL_Surface *battleship = IMG_Load("textures/battleship.png");
        SDL_Rect dstrect;
        SDL_Event event;
        dstrect.x = 1024/2;
        dstrect.y = 768/2;
        SDL_BlitSurface(battleship,NULL,level.screen,&dstrect);
        SDL_Flip(level.screen);
        while(1)
        {
            if(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            {
                if(event.key.keysym.sym==SDLK_LEFT&&dstrect.x>70)
                {
                    dstrect.x-=5;
                    battleship = IMG_Load("textures/battleship.png");
                    SDL_BlitSurface(battleship,NULL,level.screen,&dstrect);
                    SDL_Flip(level.screen);
                    event.key.keysym.sym==NULL;
                }
                if(event.key.keysym.sym==SDLK_RIGHT&&dstrect.x<(1024-200))
                {
                    dstrect.x+=5;
                    battleship = IMG_Load("textures/battleship.png");
                    SDL_BlitSurface(battleship,NULL,level.screen,&dstrect);
                    SDL_Flip(level.screen);
                    event.key.keysym.sym==NULL;
                }
                if(event.key.keysym.sym==SDLK_ESCAPE)
                {
                    exit(0);
                }
                SDL_Delay(100);
                battleship = IMG_Load("textures/battleship.png");
                SDL_BlitSurface(battleship,NULL,level.screen,&dstrect);
                SDL_Flip(level.screen);
            }
        }
   }
//private:
//friend
};
```

Comment: `cruiser cruiser(SDL_Surface *screen);` -- What is this supposed to do?  All this does is declare a function -- it doesn't call a function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i want this work all toghether
it must show background + battleship which can be moved by user

Answer (score 0):

In constructor of your class

```
cruiser(SDL_Surface *screen)
```

you are not passing an object of `class level` and inside the constructor you are trying to access a non static member variable of that class. Your constructor for `class cruiser` should take object of `class level` as an input parameter.

It should be

```
cruiser(SDL_Surface *screen, level obj_level)
{
//your stuff
}
```

constructor of `class level` should be

```
level(SDL_Surface *battleground)
{
  //your stuff
  cruiser cruiser(SDL_Surface *screen, *this);
}
```

Hope this helps.

P.S: There are various design flaws in your code and I am not addressing those here.

Comment: @Abbishek
"level(SDL_Surface *battleground)
{
  //your stuff
  cruiser cruiser(SDL_Surface *screen, *this);
}"
what means this?

Comment: @Матвей `this` is a pointer pointing to the object you are in.

Comment: @Abbishek is it   " *level "?

Comment: @Матвей it is `*this`.